# flux/utils not working when not immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm trying out with flux/utils just for an example project, and when I mutate the store directly, I get errors. But when I return a new state object, everything works fine. Previously when using the EventEmitter class I could mutate the store directly, but not with the flux/utils.

I thought Flux's (unlike Redux's) store can be mutable.

For example, when given:

```
case ADD_COUNTER: {
    state.counters.push({
        id: state.currId++,
        value: 0
    });

    return state;
}
```

and the ADD_COUNTER action is fired, nothing happens. UI stays the same.

And when given:

```
case ADD_COUNTER: {
    return {
        ...state,
        counters: [
            ...state.counters,
            {
                id: state.currId,
                value: 0
            }
        ],
        currId: state.currId + 1
    };
}
```

and the ADD_COUNTER action is fired, the state gets updated and the changes are updated in the UI.

Comment: You are a bit vague in your description of the problem, any chance you could provide an [mcve] so we could analyze your problem? Or is the last statement sentence the question you have?

Comment: Any chance you could add the UI component rendering it?